# Django Subquery, ORA-00904: invalid identifier

Tags: python, sql, django, oracle, django-models

The query below works as raw sql

```
SELECT WORK_ORDER.*,(SELECT COMPLETE FROM SAMPLE WHERE COMPLETE = 'TRUE' AND
ARF_ID = WORK_ORDER.ARF_ID AND ROWNUM <= 1) AS SAMPLE_COMPLETE, (DUE_DATE - 
SYSDATE) AS DUE_IN FROM WORK_ORDER WHERE COMPLETE = 'FALSE' ORDER BY 
DUE_DATE ASC
```

The following Django Queryset does not work

```
subquery = Sample.objects.filter(complete = 'TRUE', arf_id = models.OuterRef('arf_id'))[:1]
workOrderList = WorkOrder.objects.annotate(sample_complete= models.Subquery(subquery.values('complete'))).annotate(due_in= models.F('due_date') - datetime.now()).filter(complete = 'FALSE').order_by('due_date')
```

which produces this query when running workOrderList.query

```
SELECT "WORK_ORDER"."ARF_ID", "WORK_ORDER"."COMPANY_NAME", 
"WORK_ORDER"."COMPANY_ADDRESS", "WORK_ORDER"."CONTACT_TELEPHONE", 
"WORK_ORDER"."ORDER_DATE", "WORK_ORDER"."DUE_DATE", 
"WORK_ORDER"."ARF_NUMBER", "WORK_ORDER"."COMPLETE", 
"WORK_ORDER"."COMPLETE_DATE", "WORK_ORDER"."REPORTED", 
"WORK_ORDER"."REPORTED_DATE", "WORK_ORDER"."COMPANY_CODE", (SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT "_SUB".* FROM (SELECT U0."COMPLETE" AS Col1 FROM "SAMPLE" U0 WHERE 
(U0."COMPLETE" = TRUE AND U0."ARF_ID" = ("WORK_ORDER"."ARF_ID"))) "_SUB" 
WHERE ROWNUM <= 1)) AS "SAMPLE_COMPLETE", ("WORK_ORDER"."DUE_DATE" - 2019- 
01-28 13:00:51.043013) AS "DUE_IN" FROM "WORK_ORDER" WHERE 
"WORK_ORDER"."COMPLETE" = FALSE ORDER BY "WORK_ORDER"."DUE_DATE" ASC
```

This returns error
`cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00904: "WORK_ORDER"."ARF_ID": invalid identifier`

I am using Django 1.11.13 and this is a legacy database, I am comfortable using raw sql to query data but would like to learn/utilize the Django ORM the correct way so any fix or explanation why this won't work is helpful to me.

Comment: Django uses several nested subqueries, which apparently won't work if you reference a field from the outer query in a nested subquery, cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21580705/ora-00904-invalid-identifier-in-subquery?rq=1 – I'm not sure how to best reformulate the Django query though.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Exists() subclass in this case works is a solution to accomplish the the overall goal:

```
workOrderList = WorkOrder.objects.annotate(sample_complete= models.Exists(subquery.values('complete')))
.annotate(due_in= models.F('due_date') - datetime.now()).filter(complete = 'FALSE').order_by('due_date')
```

I am still looking for a solution that uses the Subquery() method